# Elasticsearch, solr concurrent commit

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

About three years ago we developed application that used solr, as I remember version #4. And I remember the work with solr was in two steps - add document and commit. The new document became available in index only after commit. Besides one a day optimize was made.

The problem was that with solr we couldn't use concurrent commit and there was serious time lag between db update and solr index update. However, for application we developed this lag wasn't a problem.

Now we need to develop another application and here we need almost real time indexing. Our situation - N users who can simultaneously update some data. At the moment they update data in DB there must be simultaneous update of the index. Can we do this with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of Solr can handle this situation:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch

basically, you leave the commits to the server (the application doesn't commit), and you configure the server to do very frequent (e.g. every second) soft commits, which are very cheap and make the documents available to the index in memory, and infrequent (e.g. every few minutes) hard commits, which are expensive, but write the new documents on the permanent storage.